# Struggling to convert my sql query to be set based instead of using while loops

Tags: sql-server

My code is:

```
Declare @Users table(Names nvarchar(50) not null, Flag int);
Declare @ValidUsers table(Names nvarchar(50) not null);
Declare @Office int;
Declare @NumberOfRecords int;
Declare @Count int;
Declare @IntCount int;
Declare @Binary AS nvarchar(16);
Declare @bit as nvarchar(1);
Declare @PermissionSub as nvarchar(1);
Declare @Permission as nvarchar(16);
Declare @ShouldContinue as bit;

set @ShouldContinue = 1;
set @Permission = '0001111111111111'; /* going to pass this value */
set @Count = '1';
set @IntCount = '1';
set @Office = '3'; /* going to pass this value */

Insert into @Users
    Select 
        dbUser.usrFullName, udFeeEarnerLicence.purchaseFlag
    From 
        [OMSBB].[dbo].[udFeeEarnerLicence] 
    Inner Join
        [OMSBB].[dbo].[dbUser] ON udFeeEarnerLicence.feeUsrId = dbUser.usrID
    Where 
        dbUser.brId = @Office;

select @NumberOfRecords = COUNT(Flag) from @Users;

DECLARE @Flag AS int;

select @Flag = Flag from @Users;

while(@Count <= @NumberOfRecords)
begin
    WITH CTE AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            Flag, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Flag) AS RwNr
        FROM 
            @Users
    )
    SELECT TOP(1) @Flag = Flag -- this TOP(1) is just a fail-safe
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RwNr = @Count;

    WITH A AS 
    (
        SELECT 0 AS ORD, @Flag AS NUMBER, CAST('' AS VARCHAR(20)) AS BITS

        UNION ALL

        SELECT ORD+1, NUMBER/2,  CAST(BITS+CAST(NUMBER%2 AS VARCHAR(20)) AS VARCHAR(20))
        FROM A
        WHERE  NUMBER > 0
    )
    SELECT @Binary = RIGHT('000000000000000'+ CASE WHEN BITS='' THEN '0' ELSE REVERSE(BITS) END,16)
    FROM A
    WHERE NUMBER = 0;

    WHILE (@IntCount <= 16)
    BEGIN
        select @bit = SUBSTRING(@Binary, @IntCount, @IntCount + 1);
        select @PermissionSub = SUBSTRING(@Permission, @IntCount, @IntCount + 1);

        if(@PermissionSub = '1' and @bit != '1') /* if Permission selection is required and user does not have permission*/
        begin
            SET @ShouldContinue = 0;
            break;
        end     
    end

    Set @IntCount = 0;

    if(@ShouldContinue = 0)
    begin
        continue;
    end

    ; WITH CTE AS 
    (
        SELECT Names, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Flag) AS RwNr
        FROM @Users
    )
    INSERT INTO @ValidUsers
        SELECT Names
        FROM CTE
        WHERE RwNr = @Count; 
end

select * from @ValidUsers
```

I will be adapting this code to use it inside of an SSRS report so that's why there are comments on some parameters saying that I will be passing the parameters. This code at its basics finds all users who are from a specified office and have the specified permissions. The permission a user has are set in 5 flags in this example I'm using the purchaseFlag. This value is an int and it calculated by creating an order of permissions and set their bit values to create a string of 0's and 1's and then converting that binary number into a decimal for example '8191' which the binary value of would be '0001111111111111'. I use two while loops in this one to go through the users and the other to go through each of the 16 characters in the permissions. My issue is that this I'm almost certain that this query works but it takes so long to run that I haven't seen the result of it yet and people have recommended that I use sets instead.

Comment: You should make an effort to be **consistent** with how you write the SQL keywords - *either* write them in all UPPERCASE (SELECT, FROM), or then write them in all lowercase (select, from), or all in mixed case (Select, From, Where) - but pick **one style** and then **stick to it** - don't mix and match!

Comment: If you add some sample data and expected results to the question, there is a good chance that somebody would be able to write a query. SQL Server has [Bitwise Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms176122.aspx).